# Is it possible to type inside the textbox displaying in a prompt in Cypress and click on ok button

Tags: javascript, cypress

Is it possible to type inside the `textbox` displaying in an `alert` using Cypress command and the click on `ok` inside alert. The below test display the alert message but didn't do anything.

```
describe('Type some text inside the textbox in an alert', function() {
  it.only('Type some text inside the textbox test', function() {
    cy.visit('http://sometesturl.com')
    const stub = cy.stub()
     cy.on ('window:alert', stub)
     cy
      .get('#pidforinput').click()
      .then(($stub) => {
      const myWin = $stub.find('input');
      cy.wrap(myWin ).type("This is a text box");
    })
  })
})
```

//Below is my js code to display alert and textbox inside

```
function promptMessage() {
    var favColor = prompt("What is your favorite color?", "");
    if (favColor != null){      
    alert("Your favorite color is " + favColor);        
    }
    else {
    alert("You did not specify your favorite color");
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="pidforinput" type="button" onclick="promptMessage()" value="Click here to specify your favorite color" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So right now according to the documentation of Cypress you can use stubs to change the behaviour of prompts like this

```
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000', {
  onBeforeLoad(win) {
    cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns('my custom message')
  }
})

cy.window().its('prompt').should('be.called')
cy.get('any_selector').should('have.value', 'my custom message')
```

Check [this](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub.html#Replace-built-in-window-methods-like-prompt) for further info

Comment: I am getting following CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '.name', but never found it.

Comment: Here `.name` is just an example that wherever you want the return message from the prompt. You can use any selector there. I have edited my answer there.

Comment: So can't we type the returned text into the 'textbox' field in alert and click on Ok button inside the alert ?

Comment: So here we are modifying the behaviour of prompt using [Stubs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/stubs-spies-and-clocks.html#Stubs). So essentially whatever you want to type in the text box, you can replace it with `my custom message`. It will show the same behaviour, in Cypress check [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/stubs-spies-and-clocks.html#Stubs) for handling window events.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that completely, I have understood how to returned the 'text' that need to type in via stub. But I am not clear at this step `cy.get('any_selector')..` If I need to pass the text into the `textbox` of alert message, how do we know about selector details of that text field in alert ?

Comment: the text in the confirm is already passed using `cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns('my custom message')` this. `cy.get('any_selector').should('have.value', 'my custom message')` this is used to check whether correct text is passed, you can skip this part.

Comment: Accepted the answer